# Template language that works on both server and client

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js

I am looking for a template solution that can work on both server side (like ERB) and client side (like EJS) so I don't have to write the views twice for use in, say, both Rails and [Backbone](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone).
The first that comes to mind is **Mustache**. Any others?
Anyone doing this successfully ?

EDIT

I keep a compilation [Here](https://github.com/clyfe/cywiky/wiki/Server-&-Client-Templates).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/). (Twitter used it in their recent redesign, so they can share templates between server-side Ruby and client-side JavaScript.)

It's also available in Ruby, JavaScript, Python, Erlang, PHP, Perl, Objective-C, Java, .NET, Android, C++, Go, Lua, ooc, ActionScript, ColdFusion, Scala, Clojure, Fantom, CoffeeScript, D, and for node.js.

(Yes, I know you mentioned it in your question, but this answer has links and stuff.)

Comment: nevertheless, the Twiter info is nice

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this [HAML implementation for JS](https://github.com/creationix/haml-js) (given that you're open to use HAML that is ;) ). Also the most commonly used JS templates which has been [originally suggest](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) (not sure if it has a name, actually?) by John Resig shares key elements with ERB. It's also used with [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template)'s templating functionality.

*I haven't tried to achieve what you're after yet, but thought about it a few times and I'd guess that you'll encounter problems with currently existing solutions and implementation of things like e.g. loops. Just my 5 cent.*

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Liquid templates [for Ruby](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/) and for [Javascript](https://github.com/darthapo/liquid.js).

Answer (score 0):

Try [poirot](https://github.com/olivernn/poirot).  It's a gem that makes it dead simple to reuse [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) or [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) templates client and server side.