# Share template between client and server

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, backbone.js

I am building an app - front end = backbone , server = node.js. 
In order to improve performance, I am thinking on rendering first page from node/express server, using some templating engine. On client I want to do all iterations via ajax requests (receiving json) and, again, using template to render the data (actually it is the same template).
Is there a way to reuse the same template on client and server? It will be easier to maintain / cache. The first load  of the template on the server has other advantages like server routing + option to determind which template to return according to user agent.
Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977558/template-language-that-works-on-both-server-and-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ECT](http://ectjs.com) template engine. ECT designed for use on client and server without any modifications in templates and code. Also ECT most [fastest](http://ectjs.com/#benchmark) template engine for now.